# Get rates for all services in one request

Tags: ups

#### Question

Is it possible to get rates for all possible ups services in the same request?

#### Background

Although the UPS rates documentation states that the `service` element is optional
[image: proof of optionality]

Requests with the `service` element defined respond successfully while requests without the element defined result in the following error:

```
["Error"]=>
array(3) {
  ["ErrorSeverity"]=>
  string(4) "Hard"
  ["ErrorCode"]=>
  string(6) "111100"
  ["ErrorDescription"]=>
  string(58) "The requested service is invalid from the selected origin."
}
```

Additionally, every example and library i've seen either only desired to create requests for one type of service or [creates a request for each service the user specifies they want to receive](https://github.com/uh-opensource/node-shipping-ups):

> // optional, you can specify which rates to look for -- performs multiple requests, so be careful not to do too many

#### In Summary

Is there a way to return rates for all services from UPS that I am missing or must we query UPS for each service we wish to get a rate for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to receive rates for multiple services by setting the `/RateRequest/Request/RequestOption` to `Shop` and omitting the `/RateRequest/Shipment/Service` element.

This is outlined in UPS's documentation for the Rate Webservice endpoints:

> Can a customer compare services for a shipment using the Rating API?
>
> Yes. Use the “Shop” value, instead of the “Rate” value, in the RequestOption element of the ../Request container to retrieve the rates for all services for the stated lane pair. The API response will return a rate for each of the available services. This is known as the Shop option.